# Reading a .ddd file to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'am using this (very usefull) C# library *https://github.com/jugglingcats/tachograph-reader* to parsing .ddd files.

The problem is that for more .ddd files that I analyze the xml, generated by the library, shows the Node "DataBufferIsWrapperd" set to true. And the xml file doesn't contain all the driver activity of the ddd file.

While if all the activities are present, the label "DataBufferIsWrapperd" is set to false.

What is the problem? Why the data are cut in the xml file?

Comment: If the project has a bug, maybe you should open a ticket with the project owner.

Comment: Posts like this are unlikely to get help here as if the issue is with the library you will need to approach the library developers or community. 

also in future examples of your issue and a desired outcome would be useful along with a minimal example

Comment: The code is using XmlWriter.  I can't find where the writer is created but code should look like this : XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("filename", settings);

Comment: how did you get this library to compile ? I downloaded and tried to use it today, but when compiling I get hundreds of errors...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is fairly simple I suspect.

If you can imagine a .ddd (DriverCard download) file contains what is effectively an array of driver activities.

So it's going to look like:

```
Index    TimeStamp          Activity
0        2018-01-07 04:00   DRIVE
1        2018-01-07 04:30   REST
2        2018-01-07 04:45   WORK
...
...
```

When the card is new, the array is filled one by one so that the latest entry is at index = (activity count -1). e.g. if there are 10 activities so the latest is at index 9 in the activity array stored on the card.

Once the card has been used for a long period of time, the tachograph will wrap the activity array, for the simple reason that driver cards have very limited storage space (in the thousands of activities), meaning the low indexes in the activity array will have a later timestamp than the later indexes.

```
Index    TimeStamp          Activity
0        2018-09-01 06:11   DRIVE
1        2018-01-07 04:00   DRIVE
2        2018-01-07 04:30   REST
3        2018-01-07 04:45   WORK
...
...
```

Handling this wrapped data is quite tricky, I know because I've written a .DDD parser myself. I believe that the library you're using may not be handling wrapped data properly, this is why you're only seeing some of the activities.

The way it actually works is slightly more complex, and there are quite a few ways to go wrong parsing this data. Effectively driver cards with wrapped data are likely exposing an issue with the library.

You might be able to understand a little more about the problem if you can see which of the activities are missing, the earlier or the later.

Comment: Hi Terry. I saw that you wrote an .ddd reader yourself ... after long researches, I have arrived here, and when I have read this, I get hope: can you tell me, or better, give a documentation about this ? I am struggle to read .ddd files with C++, and  can read this file as byte array, but I don't know how to interpret this byte array ... can you guide me a little bit ? My email is flaviu2@yahoo.com. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, there's a PDF doc that describes the .ddd format. It's very detailed, so it should allow you to parse files. I'll send it on!

Comment: Here's a link for the PD, it details all the data structures use and the layout of the 4 types of tachograph card (driver, workshop, control company, plus the VU as well). The layout of the driver card is on page 126 I think. I'll send to your email as well: https://www.dropbox.com/s/moymz9hby9j1331/TachographSpec.pdf?dl=0